# How does console/shell caching/restoration work?

Tags: linux, caching, ssh, terminal, konsole

*This question is purely out of curiosity; there's no problem to be resolved.*

Note: I'm using Konsole on CentOS 7.

When I SSH to a remote box and leave the session inactive for a while, it times out. As a workaround, I use `less [some-file]` to keep the session active.

Obviously the sessions still break when I suspend the VM at the end of the day.

The next day when I start a new SSH session, everything is normal **except** that some Konsole functionality doesn't work (namely, clearing scrollback, which I use a lot) for the same terminal window used for the SSH session.

However, after I `less` a file and quit, two things happen:

1. Konsole resumes working normally.
2. Whatever output was in the terminal before I used `less` is replaced with whatever output was there the previous day, before the session was broken by shutting down the VM I'm SSHing from.

Curiously, this happens for all ~4 concurrent terminals/sessions (each one having its output from the previous day restored). [edit: clarification: each of the ~4 terminals exhibits this behavior when I SSH/less in that particular terminal. Each one resumes its output from the day before. Doing this in one terminal/session is **not** affecting the other terminals/sessions]

I assume this would happen with any terminal app (e.g. vi, nano, etc.) with its own "gui" and isn't specific to `less`.

Seems like there's some caching going on. I assume quitting `less` (or vi, nano, etc.) triggers some sort of shell output restoration in general, but this particular manifestation seems somewhat odd.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: There are several buffers you/the applications can switch between in the terminal, if I am right. But I can't remember the actual name of that mechanisms so I am unable to help more. But I would be interested in answers too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *terminal* feature described in the question the *alternate screen* feature (originally `xterm`, but copied/imitated by several other terminals including `konsole`).  Depending on the terminal description, you may/may not use this feature.

`less` and most full-screen terminal programs such as `vi` send the escape sequences to switch to/from alternate screen if they're defined in the terminal description (i.e., `TERM=xterm`).

From the description, it sounds as if you're using different tabs in the same instance of `konsole`, and that it's remembering that your terminal was set to the alternate screen.  `konsole` and some other programs attempt to save/restore "session" information when halted, so that probably seemed like a good thing to save/restore.

While in the alternate screen, terminal programs typically have little or no access to the scrollback region.

You can use `tput` to send the same escape sequence (without running `less`):

```
tput rmcup
```

(If the terminal description doesn't *have* a definition for that, it'll do nothing).

Further reading:

- [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)